# Django: remove duplicates (group by) from queryset by related model field

Tags: python, django

I have a Queryset with a couple of records, and I wan't to remove duplicates using the related model field. For example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group')
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
    ...
    models.ForeignKey('User')

addresses = Address.objects.filter(user__group__id=1).order_by('-id')
```

This returns a QuerySet of Address records, and I want to group by the User ID.

- I can't use `.annotate` because I need all fields from Address, and the relationship between Address and User
- I can't use `.distinct()` because it doesn't work, since all addresses are distinct, and I want distinct user addresses.

I could:

```
addresses = Address.objects.filter(user__group__id=1).order_by('-id')
unique_users_ids = []
unique_addresses = []

for address in addresses:
    if address.user.id not in unique_users_ids:
        unique_addresses.append(address)
        unique_users_ids.append(address.user.id)

print unique_addresses # TA-DA!
```

But it seems too much for a simple thing like a group by (damn you Django).

Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Comment: How are `Address` and `Group` related? We only see that `Address` is related to `User`, and `User` to group, so wouldn't the query be `user__group__id=1`?

Comment: Not related at all.

Comment: Furthermore we can not perform a `GROUP BY`, since it is rather unclear how you would "aggregate" over multiple addresses.

Comment: but then the `group__id=1` query does not make much sense.

Comment: oops, it was a typo

Comment: Say that there are two addresses for a single user, then which address should be selected?

Comment: The latest: `.order_by('-id')`

Answer (score 7):

## By using `.distinct()` with a field name

Django has also a [**`.distinct(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) function that takes as input column the column names that should be unique. Alas most database systems do not support this (only PostgreSQL to the best of my knowledge). But in PostgreSQL we can thus perform:

```
# Limited number of database systems support this
addresses = (Address.objects
                    .filter(user__group__id=1)
                    .order_by('-id')
                    .distinct('user_id'))
```

## By using two queries

Another way to handle this is by first having a query that works over the users, and for each user obtains the largest `address_id`:

```
from django.db.models import Max

address_ids = (User.objects
                   .annotate(address_id=Max('address_set__id'))
                   .filter(address_id__isnull=False)
                   .values_list('address_id'))
```

So now for every user, we have calculated the largest corresponding `address_id`, and we eliminate `User`s that have no address. We then obtain the list of `id`s.

In a second step, we then fetch the addresses:

```
addresses = Address.objects.filter(pk__in=address_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. I had a really specific query, using `filter()`, `extra()`, `order_by()`, and I needed to dedupe it all (~1M records), with a specific requirement (I had to dedupe this large queryset but also keep track of what had been deduped, etc). Maybe if I had a PhD in Django ORM I could've pulled it off, but the only realistic thing was to rewrite it all in raw SQL. But in the end, just making two queries, with one as a filter reference, did the trick.